# Gradle: Meecrowave plugin not found

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to configure meecrowave gradle plugin according to this [documentation](https://github.com/apache/meecrowave/blob/b4fa7b39b199164fadb981bba33d10aa40186682/meecrowave-doc/src/main/jbake/content/meecrowave-gradle/index.adoc):

This is my script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.apache.meecrowave:meecrowave-gradle-plugin:1.2.6"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave'
}

meecrowave {
    httpPort = 9090
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-bin.zip'.
Build file '/home/jcabre/projectes/digital/espaidoc/security/build.gradle' line: 12
Plugin [id: 'org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
Plugin [id: 'org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

I've also tried with:´

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave' version '1.2.6'
}
```

Then I get this message:

```
Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-bin.zip'.
Build file '/home/jcabre/projectes/digital/espaidoc/security/build.gradle' line: 12
Plugin [id: 'org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave', version: '1.2.6'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave:org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave.gradle.plugin:1.2.6')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
Plugin [id: 'org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave', version: '1.2.6'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave:org.apache.meecrowave.meecrowave.gradle.plugin:1.2.6')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

**PARENT GRADLE**

```
plugins {
    id "base"
    id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '1.6.8' apply false
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '2.0' apply false
    id 'fish.payara.micro-gradle-plugin' version '1.0.0' apply false
}

apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/java.gradle"
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/spotbugs.gradle"
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/checkstyle.gradle"
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/pmd.gradle"
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/jacoco.gradle"
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/repositories.gradle"
apply from: "$projectDir/gradle/payara.gradle"
```

Comment: I think you forget "I've also tried with:" this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to let you know that the plugin id issue was not a "renaming" but a forgotten renaming (originally meecrowave was named microwave before joining openwebbeans project).

I fixed the plugin id in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MEECROWAVE-186 and updated the doc to reflect that. Note that the doc is not in the sources itself but online at http://openwebbeans.apache.org/meecrowave/meecrowave-gradle/index.html.

Romain

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this plugin is not published to the official [Gradle plugins portail](https://plugins.gradle.org/) , so you cannot use `plugins {}` DSL (or you need to configure the `pluginManagement.resolutionStrategy`, see [enter link description here](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/userguide/plugins.html#example_plugin_resolution_strategy) )

The other problem is that the  [documentation](https://github.com/apache/meecrowave/blob/b4fa7b39b199164fadb981bba33d10aa40186682/meecrowave-doc/src/main/jbake/content/meecrowave-gradle/index.adoc) you mentioned is not up-to-date !
The plugin ID has been changed to `org.apache.microwave.microwave`

Easiest way to apply this plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.apache.meecrowave:meecrowave-gradle-plugin:1.2.6"
    }
}

// use "new" plugin ID
apply plugin: "org.apache.microwave.microwave"

// or use directly PLugin class
//apply plugin: org.apache.meecrowave.gradle.MeecrowavePlugin
```

**EDIT** see Romain's answer for more accurate details about this issue.